# Parsing the JXDatePicker in order to insert into Java DB Date field?

Tags: java, swingx

I'd like to insert the value derived from this JXDatePicker into a Date field in Java DB. How should I get ONLY date off this controller in a way that time is represented as dd/mm/yyyy and nothing else??!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the `Date` from the `JXDatePicker.getDate()` and then use a `SimpleDateFormat` to format the date into the required format.

Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
formater.format(myDatePicker.getDate());
```

Notice that instead of the `mm` that you've used I used `MM` to represent the month.  Please see the `SimpleDateFormat` [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for pattern letters you can use.

**Follow-Up**

I feel compelled to mention, for completeness, that it is generally a bad idea to put formatted strings representing dates into a database; what happens when you want to display it in another format, for instance, or do a simple comparison using `SQL`.

One way to store date/times is to use the timestamp that you get from `Date.getTime()`.  Here's the `Date` class' `getTime()` [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setTime%28long%29):

> Returns the number of **milliseconds** since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>   represented by this Date object.

Storing this representation of a `Date` in your database makes it much simpler to create a `Date` object when you retrieve the timestamp:

```
Long myTimeStamp = getTimeStampFromResultSet();
Date date = new Date(myTimeStamp);
```

Or use the column in `SQL` to do a simple comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_DATE > ?
```

It also makes it somewhat portable so you can, for instance, send the timestamp to a thin client that is built using a different technology.

That being said, it is also in your best interest to use a date and time library like [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead of using the unreliable and inconvenient Java `Date` or `Calendar` classes.

Comment: Thanks a million!  Could you please let me know how would you do it with time as well??!

Comment: Sure, just use the time pattern letters as documented in the javadocs; such as `hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Cool! You are a super star!  Saved my day :-)

Comment: Glad I could help.  You should definitely spend some time getting to know the `SimpleDateFormat` class and the pattern letters see the javadoc link in the answer.